# How to get Offline Document version of ngdocs Web Application?

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc, grunt-ngdocs

I am using ngdocs for documention of  my Angular JS Project.
Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ngdocs

Running **gulp ngdocs** generates the docs folder , which is an Angular Application to show the JS DOcs.

How can i convert this Web App into a document?

Say, a word Document?

Comment: So you have the documentation in a HTML page and, for goodness knows what reason, you want to convert the page to MSWord? Is that your question? Or are you trying to ask something else?

Comment: @jwpfox....Yes...that was my question...:)..I think the idea essentially is horrible...But, yes...thats what my question is..

Comment: The minimalist answer is to view the source on the HTML page, copy it into a HTML text file, open the HTML file in word and save it as DOC/DOCX. Far from elegant and not scalable but if you only have a few pages to do it should work with minimal overhead. Not a great suggestion, I know :)

Comment: @jwpfox....Thanks for the suggestion!....I l keep it in mind....I am not having an immediate need for converting into word anymore...but thanks!